# Why was the Samaritan facility in South Africa instead of somewhere much closer?

Tags: person-of-interest

Why was the Samaritan facility

> Shaw was held at

in South Africa, instead of somewhere much, much closer? Greer would have to be flying for 14 hours 35 minutes from New York to Johannesburg, each way, frequently—at least every episode we saw him there.

Answer (score 1):

### It's a black site

I believe it's not stated in the show, but presumably the main reason is that the activity you mention could not legally be performed within the U.S. Thus, it must take place at a [black site](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_site). I'm not familiar with the relevant laws, but if Poland can host a CIA black site, presumably so could South Africa.

There's also less chance of accidental discovery by Americans, who are probably the only people who might have *any* influence over the people responsible for Samaritan. American voters and rich people are a lot less likely to notice or care if someone in South Africa announces that they've stumbled across a mysterious, high-security facility.

Finally, it's an extra layer of defense against escapes if the prisoners are unfamiliar with the culture and geography of the area outside the prison. An escapee will have a harder time making good their escape, orienting themselves, accessing funds, and making their way back to whatever American community their life or project lies in.